# Dimension of representation of symmetric group $\mathcal S_n$

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups

Is there a notion of dimension of representation of symmetric group $\mathcal S_n$ over $\Bbb F_2^k$? What is this dimension $k$?

In general is there a notion of dimension of representation of symmetric group $\mathcal S_n$ over $\Bbb K^k$ where $\Bbb K$ is an arbitrary field? Is there a general formula?

Are there multiple notions or is there standard notion?

---

I am studying this indirectly. I take a complete graph and take its Aut group which is $\mathcal S_n$. I want to label **edges** by vectors in $\Bbb F_2^k$ so that sum of labels over simple cycles are not part of kernel. I want to know the minimum $k$ that can do this. I am thinking dimension of aut group is same as $k$. I am trying to show this.

Comment: Yes, as a representation is a vector space with an action of the group. Do you mean something else by representation?

Comment: I think this will do for now. Is it $k\approx n\log n$ for $\Bbb F_2^k$ if symmetric group is $\mathcal S_n$?

Comment: How would it be that? It is a dimension, so it is clearly a natural number.

Comment: Are you actually trying to ask what the minimal dimension of a faithful representation of $S_n$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$ is, or something like that?

Comment: need not be faithful

Comment: It might help if you wrote the definition of representation you use.

Comment: If $n \geq 6$ is even, $S_{n}$ has a faithful representation of degree $n-2$ over $\mathbb{F}_{2}$.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson could you be more explicit? Is there a reference?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I am studying this indirectly. I take a complete graph and take its Aut group which is $\mathcal S_n$. I want to label edges by vectors in $\Bbb F_2^k$ so that sum of labels over simple cycles are not part of kernel. I want to know the minimum $k$ that can do this. I am thinking dimension of aut group is same as $k$. I am trying to show this.

Comment: Take the natural permutation representation of degree $1$, and let $V$ be the associated $\mathbb{F}_{2}$-module, identified with column vectors under left multiplication by permutation matrices. Then $V$ has a sudmodule $W$ consisting of column vectors with the sum of the entries $0$, which is $S_{n}$-invariant.  But $W$ itself has a submodule $U$ consisting of vectors with all entries equal ( this uses the fact that $n$ is even). Then $W/U$ is a module for $S_{n}$ of dimension $n-2$, and is easily checked to be  faithful when $n \geq 6$. This can be found in many texts, eg G. James.

Comment: @EricWofsey updated